# Workspace Api not returning focused tab details

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience, summer-18, contentworkspace

I am trying close a custom tab in Lightning Console App from my lightning component. And i am getting below error:

"Error: Could not locate focused tab"

**Component**:

```
<lightning:workspaceAPI aura:id="workspace"/>
<lightning:button variant="neutral" label="Cancel" onclick="{!c.backToOpp}"/>
```

**Controller**:

```
var workspaceTab = cmp.find("workspace"); 
            workspaceTab.getFocusedTabInfo().then(function(response) {
            console.log('response' +JSON.stringify(response));
            var focusedTabId = response.tabId;
            workspaceTab.closeTab({tabId: focusedTabId});
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            console.log('response' +JSON.stringify(response));
            console.log(error);
        });
```

On click of a button i need to close current custom tab(which has my lightning component) and go back  to opportunity tab.(I am using to navigateToSobject to do this).

I even tried getPrimaryTabId and getAllTabsInfo but i am getting similar exception.

Can some please help me to understand what i am doing is possible or i am missing something here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot use navigateToSobject as it changes the tab structure and Id, and hence you get **"Error: Could not locate focused tab"**.  When in console app, always stick with Console API. So you have to get focussedTab first, then open a new tab, then close the old tap. The below code does the same.

```
closeFocusedTabAndOpenNewTab : function(component, event, helper) {
        var workspaceAPI = component.find("workspace");
        workspaceAPI.getFocusedTabInfo().then(function(response) {
            var focusedTabId = response.tabId;
            console.log(focusedTabId);

            //Opening New Tab
            workspaceAPI.openTab({
                url: '#/sObject/0012800000GoPBQAA3/view'
            }).then(function(response) {
                workspaceAPI.focusTab({tabId : response});
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
                console.log(error);
            });

            //Closing old one
            workspaceAPI.closeTab({tabId: focusedTabId});
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }
```

Comment: sorry for delayed response, thanks this helped me to get what i was looking for :)

Comment: Can you please help me on how and what occurances and the purpose of getenclosingtabId does do?