# Issue with closing tab using Lightning Console API

Tags: lightning-console

I have a requirement to replace a primary tab in lightning console with another record.  I have tried to implement it the way described in [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/219610/workspace-api-not-returning-focused-tab-details) link.  When I call closeTab, I am always getting what looks like an internal error:

**[PromiseRejection: Error: getTabInfo() - Failed to get tabInfo for tabId `ctab0`]
t.$$lwcEventWrapper$$()@https://***--devsis.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/uZhR234ENYM5YJpipvJEkg/aura_prod.js:2:14001**

Even if I comment out opening the tab, I get the same error, so the error seems to be an issue with closeTab.  This is using Summer 19.  Has anyone been able to successfully use this logic in Summer 19?

Comment: not getting any error. if possible, can you show your code?

Comment: Posted below...

Comment: Looks like someone has seen something similar to this: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/254115/lex-console-method-issue-lightningtabclosed

Comment: Can you show the html code where you are invoking `goToAcct`?

Answer (score 0):

```
goToAcct : function(component, event, helper) {
var acid = event.target.id;

var workspaceAPI = component.find("workspace");
    workspaceAPI.getFocusedTabInfo().then(function(response) {
        var focusedTabId = response.tabId;
        console.log(focusedTabId);

        //Opening New Tab
        workspaceAPI.openTab({
           pageReference: {
      type: "standard__recordPage",
      attributes: {
        recordId: acid,
        actionName: "view"
      },
      state: {}
    },
    focus: true
        }).then(function(response) {
            workspaceAPI.focusTab({tabId : response});
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        });

        //Closing old one
        // workspaceAPI.closeTab({tabId: focusedTabId});
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
```

}

Answer (score 0):

This is a false flag, the issue was due to a handler being called when the tab was closed, which was trying to look at the closed (and therefore non existent) tab.

Comment: This is still happening in our UAT org, when we close tab.

Comment: Like I said, it is probably a side effect of something else.