# Cannot assign to read only property 'disconnectedHandler' of object '[object Object]

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components

I am trying to work with a timer in Salesforce Lightning. When I add it to the page, it throws the error of "**render threw an error in 'c:serviceConsoleCaseTimer' [Cannot assign to read only property 'disconnectedHandler' of object '[object Object]']**" I have no clue how to fix this error.
 Here is the code where I am getting this error:

```
set tabclosed(value){
        this._tabclosed = value;
        this.tabisclosed = this._tabclosed;
        if(this.tabisclosed){
            this.disconnectedHandler();
        }
    }


    constructor(params){
        super(params)

        this.disconnectedHandler = this.disconnectedHandler.bind(this)
        this.pauseTimer = this.pauseTimer.bind(this)
     }

    connectedCallback() {
        if(this.autoStart){              
            this.start();
        }
        window.addEventListener("beforeunload", this.disconnectedHandler); 
    }       

    // Function for detecting window navigation/closing 
    disconnectedHandler(){
        if(this.stime !== '00:00:00'){       
        this.stop();        
        newSession({caseId: this.recordId, timeVal: this.stime}).then(() => {
            })
            .catch(error => {
            });
        }
    }
```

I understand that the property is read only. I have tried to set the property writable : true as well.

Here are the links that I have tried:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Read-only
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57591012/ngrx-cannot-assign-to-read-only-property-property-of-object-object
[Workspace Api not returning focused tab details](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/219610/workspace-api-not-returning-focused-tab-details)

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Why are you trying to bind the function? It should already be bound to `this`, effectively meaning that this code would do nothing even if it worked.

Comment: I was trying instantiate them in the constructor so that when window opens, timer starts itself. What do you think that should be done?

Comment: can you provide playground link?

Comment: @sfdcfox you were right about the bind. I was able to solve it by removing the bind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
set tabclosed(value){
        this._tabclosed = value;
        this.tabisclosed = this._tabclosed;
        if(this.tabisclosed){
            this.disconnectedHandler();
        }
    }


    constructor(params){
        super(params)

        this.disconnectedHandler()
        this.pauseTimer()
    }

    connectedCallback() {
        if(this.autoStart){              
            this.start();
        }
        window.addEventListener("beforeunload", this.disconnectedHandler); 
    }       

    // Function for detecting window navigation/closing 
    disconnectedHandler(){
        if(this.stime !== '00:00:00'){       
        this.stop();        
        newSession({caseId: this.recordId, timeVal: this.stime}).then(() => {
            })
            .catch(error => {
            });
        }
    }
```